# Cannot get the callback for windows focus change using hook proceduce

Tags: c++, c++11, winapi, windows-10-universal

I am using this method to install local hook to detect change in window:

```
HHOOK hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT,CBTProc,NULL,(DWORD)GetCurrentThreadId());
```

The callback function is here,

```
LRESULT CALLBACK CBTProc(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {

 printf("got the window\n");`

 if (code == HCBT_SETFOCUS){

    printf("Here i got the window\n");
}
return CallNextHookEx(0, code, wParam, lParam); }
```

This callback function doesnt get called. I tried using WH_SHELL WITH `setwindowshookex` that also didnt get called. However, the return of hHook is fine and there is no error as i printed the `lasterror()` also. May be i am missing something. Is the dll necessary to be created? or i can do it directly using exe.

Comment: You may need to check if code < 0 in first place and if that's the case to CallNextHookEx(hHook, code, wParam, lParam); Mind the hHook parameter which you should take from the SetWindowsHookEx call. You need to keep the hHook in a #pragma shared section in order to access it from a hook dll (for global hooks). After that you can check if (code == HCBT_SETFOCUS): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644960(v=vs.85).aspx.
 If this doesn't fix it then maybe you can try WH_GETMESSAGE hook instead.

Comment: i included the changes, but still doesnot get callback, i also tested with WH_GETMESSAGE, same result. I am trying to do without using dll. I am also using lowlevel keyboard hook, that part works fine.I want to match application with the keystroke(global hooks) without using dlls.

Comment: In order to make it work, you need to put this code into a dll and make it a global hook as per the link I provided.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use CBTProc you need to place this code into a DLL to create a global hook. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644960(v=vs.85).aspx) clearly explains how to use global hooks. 
In your code you need to check

```
if (code < 0)
```

in first place and if that's the case to

```
CallNextHookEx(hHook, code, wParam, lParam);
```

Mind the hHook parameter which you should take from the SetWindowsHookEx call. You need to keep the hHook in a #pragma shared section in order to access it from a hook dll (for global hooks). After that you can check

```
if (code == HCBT_SETFOCUS)
```